# How can I deploy a package to a private npm repository from Circleci?

Tags: npm, circleci, npm-publish

I have read through many stack overflow questions and official documentation from Circleci but for some reason it will not let me publish packages via ci/cd.

No matter what I do I consistently get the following

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJECj.png)

I have reset the NPM_TOKEN and know that it is correct and I don't see the issue with my code. according to the docs it should work but it does not. Am I missing something obvious?

Here is what I have tried

```
jobs:
   publish: 
    executor: node 
    steps:    
      - checkout
      - install
      - run: 
          name: Build package
           command: yarn build // tsc builds package to the lib directory
      - run:
          name: Authenticate with registry 
          command: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > ~/.npmrc
      - run:
          name: Publish library
          command: npm publish lib
```

also

```
 jobs:
    publish:
      executor: node
      steps:
        - checkout
        - install
        - run:
            name: Build package 
            command: yarn build // tsc builds package to the lib directory
        - run: 
            name: Authenticate with registry 
            command: echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > ~/project/.npmrc
        - run:
            name: Publish library   
            command: npm publish lib
```

and

```
 jobs:
     publish:
       executor: node 
       steps: 
         - checkout 
         - install     
         - run:
             name: Build package 
             command: yarn build   
         - run:
             name: Publish library
             command: |
               npm set //registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=$NPM_TOKEN
               npm publish lib
```

and a few other variations but they were more tinkering, the above are examples that I have seen as documentation

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by _"it will not let me publish packages via ci/cd"_? Do you get an error message? Does the build fail?

Comment: The error message is in the description

Comment: This might be a silly question, but shouldn't you create/populate `.npmrc` in the `lib` directory?